# Create a .pdf file from various other .pdf files w/ navigable index and page numbers via python

Tags: python, indexing, auto-generate, file-management, page-numbering

There must be a simple solution to this question:

"Create a .pdf file from various other .pdf files w/ navigable index and page numbers via python."

All files are in the same folder, and all are .pdf files.
I want each filename to contain in the index and the index as a starting page.

What packages do you think fits my needs best?

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is the wrong page to ask for software or package recommendations. SO is there to help you out, if you have problems with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/

You have to split each page that you want and to add to your new pdf file.